# Two dimensional array of object, assign sub class

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-arrays, assign

I know it is posible when a have vector type MapField * and i want to push_back() type ShipField, but how about dynamic arrays? It is possible to assingn type ShipField to mapfield array after Map::Map constructor and how do that?

```
class Map
{
public:
    Map(const int mapsize);
    virtual ~Map();
    //GETTERS
    MapField **get_mapfields();
    //SETTERS;
    bool check_ships();
    bool shoot(Field * field);
private:
    const int mapsize;
    MapField **mapfields;
    std::vector<Ship *> ships;
};
```

//

```
class MapField 
    : public Field
{
public:
    MapField();
    MapField(int x, int y);
    virtual ~MapField();
    //GETTERS
    bool get_shoot_down();
    //SETTERS
    void set_shoot_down(bool shoot_down);
protected:
    bool shoot_down;
};
```

//

```
   class ShipField :
    public MapField
{
public:
    ShipField(Ship *ship, int x, int y);
    virtual ~ShipField();
    //GETTERS
    Ship* get_ship();
    //SETTERS
    void set_ship(Ship * ship);

public:
    Ship *ship;

};
```

//

```
Map::Map(const int mapsize)
    :
    mapsize(mapsize)
{
    this->mapfields = new MapField* [mapsize];
    for (int i = 0; i < mapsize; i++)
        this->mapfields[i] = new MapField[mapsize];
}
```

Comment: Yes. Just assign it. But there are no two dimensional arrays here.

Comment: A `std::vector` *is* a dynamic "array". Use it. And yes you can have nested vectors.

Comment: MapField **mapfields;
it is not two dimentional dynamic array?

Comment: @Felipe it is..

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's a pointer to pointer to `MapField`. It can be *used* as a simple dynamic array of arrays, but it isn't one. However, `std::vector<std::vector<MapField>>` is dynamic in ways your pointer to pointer never can be. Can easily be initialized in the `Map` constructor initializer list as `mapfields(mapsize, std::vector<MapField>(mapsize))`.

To make it use polymorphic classes, you need to use pointers. For this I recommend [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr):

```
class Map
{
public:
    Map(std::size_t const mapsize)
        : mapsize(mapsize),
          mapfields(mapsize, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MapField>>(mapsize))
    {}
    ...
    std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MapField>>> mapfields;
};
```

To add a new mapfield you create it at a specific location in the vectors:

```
mapfields[x][y] = std::make_shared<MapField>();
mapfields[x][y + 1] = std::make_shared<ShipField>();
```